# How does indexing with boolean work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I saw a construction, which I could not understand and did not know how to search for. It's this snippet :

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Start",[' ', i][i > 5],"End", sep="")
```

So how does `[' ', i][i > 5]` exactly work? I can see, that if the condition in the second list is fulfilled, the second argument is being selected, otherwise the first, which is white space. Any logical and general explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second list is not a list its the indexing operator

```
xs = [10,20,30]
xs[0] # gives 10
```

and its perfectly possible to use it on a list literal instead of a list variable

```
[10,20,30][0] # gives 10
```

As for the `x < 5`, When you use a boolean to index a list in Python it gets converted to 0 and 1. Try doing `xs[False]` and `xs[True]`

---

I would definitely not recommend writing that kind of code though. Its very confusing and unintuitive.

Comment: All clear now. It is indeed confusing and unintuitive, but at the say time showed me some flexibility of the language, which I found interesting.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer using the ternary operator for this kind of thing: `i if i > 5 else ''`

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't two lists, it is a single list that is *indexed* by the boolean value `i > 5`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
collection = [" ", i]
index = int(i > 5)
print(collection[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

This formulation is much beloved of a certain style of programmer, but frankly its obscurity makes me want to scream. Why write code that will take someone 30 seconds to comprehend when it is easier (and probably no slower) to use other, more comprehensible, techniques?

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Start", i if i > 5 else " ", "End", sep="")
```

makes a lot more sense to me: it's less tricksy and (I contend) far easier to understand.